# Get all links in <a> tag inside li in an ol

Tags: parsing, xpath, html-agility-pack

```
<dl id="narrow-by-list">
<dt class="odd">Category</dt>
<dd class="odd">
<ol>
<li>
<a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple/mac?cat=11">MacBook Pro</a>
(7)
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple/mac?cat=12">MacBook Air</a>
(4)
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple/mac?cat=485">MacBook </a>
(2)
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple/mac?cat=13">iMac</a>
(12)
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple/mac?cat=14">Mac Mini</a>
(5)
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple/mac?cat=15">Mac Pro</a>
(2)
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://www.shophive.com/apple/mac?cat=22">Accessories</a>
(127)
</li>
</ol>
</dd>
```

//i want to get all the href inside a tag in li which is in ol inside a class named "odd" i have tried everything by combing them into 1 div as well,

```
var getcatgory = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
    @"//d1[@id='narrow-by-list']/div[@class='odd']/ol/li")
```

i have checked NodeCollection as well,but that is returning null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your sample HTML, `dl` doesn't have child element `div[@class='odd']`, it should've been `dd[@class='odd']` instead. So this is one possible XPath to return the target `<a>` elements :

```
//dl[@id='narrow-by-list']/dd[@class='odd']/ol/li/a
```

Demo : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/7e565607576421eac5a6a273af847011

Answer (score 0):

It should be `//dl` (letter `l`), not `//d1` (digit `1`).

Comment: i have checked that, it is neither a digit nor a letter like (one or i) it is dl,i have copied that and tried but still returning null,not even accessing that id anyway